# In quirks mode is it possible to have img's resize to their containing table cell?

Tags: html, css, quirks-mode

This may seem like a blast from the past but due to project constraints I am stuck with quirks mode and tables...

The tables that i'm dealing with have a single image in each cell where all the cells should be the same size. The tables width and height are set as percentages of a parent container.

The problem is the images don't resize down, they stay at their original size seemingly no matter what I do. Then the table doesn't adhere to its set size, it has resized to hold all of the images. In standards mode I believe 'width: 100%' on the image gets closer to what I want to achieve.

I'm considering a javascript solution which loops over each image calculating what their size should be and resizing manually. But this is probably going to cause a bit of a loading time at the start which isn't ideal.

**Edit:**

I have written a basic example at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/emudo/4). What I want to achieve is to be able to set the size of the table and have the images resize, whether growing or shrinking to their cell.

The 4th jsbin revision uses the dummy images.

Comment: Are you talking about Quirks Mode in only Internet Explorer? (other browsers also have it) Could you make a quick [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) example of the code you're working with so we don't have to?

Comment: At this stage i've only confirmed its quirks in Internet Explorer but as far as I know the doctype i'm using triggers quirks in all browsers: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

Comment: That doctype *will* trigger Quirks Mode in all browsers. Quirks Mode "IE" and Quirks Mode "Other Browsers" can be different. What I meant was "What browsers is your project being used in? Just Internet Explorer? Is this an internal project?". (A test case would still help here. In fact, I'm not going to try to solve this without one. You can use http://dummyimage.com/ to easily generate test images.)

Comment: Thanks thirtydot, I didn't know about either of these services. It is not an internal project so as a requirement it needs to be cross browser. We support IE8, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: That demo, it looks broken as you described in Firefox. However, I think it already looks correct in IE8. Is that case - does it already look correct in IE8?

Comment: You are right, that example did look fine in IE8. I'm getting confused with quite unreliable results. I made a new revision /6/ which added more rows and columns and that seemed to fix it in firefox. I think I need to play around a bit more. There is a chance that in my working (non example) version other styles are affecting this.

Comment: Ah, it seems to be to do with the number of rows and columns. It looks like the browser will only resize the image down to a certain amount. Testing with 10 columns, 4 rows and the problem shows up in IE8. Firefox displays correctly. http://jsbin.com/emudo/7

Comment: http://jsbin.com/emudo/8 now chrome won't display it properly either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I've solved this.

I've tested this demo in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari, Opera; they all render consistently.

- I had to add a wrapper `div` in each cell. I know this isn't awesome, but it had to be done to make it work in Chrome.
- I added `table-layout: fixed` to make it work in Internet Explorer.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/emudo/9)

**CSS:**

```
#mycontainer {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#mytable {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#mytable div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#mytable img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mycontainer">
    <table id="mytable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td><div><img src="http://dummyimage.com/28x28/000/fff.png&text=Dummy" /></div></td>
            ...
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thirtydot I didn't think I was going to hear back from you! I'll give your answer a go now. CSS > JavaScript for this solution.

Comment: Also my JavaScript was far from perfect, it was messing up something else on the page.

Comment: It's funny, I posted my answer a whole *15 seconds* after yours :) Hope this works!

Comment: Works perfectly in all browsers. Such a simple and elegant solution. Thank you greatly.

Comment: In my tests it seems to be working even without the divs. The main thing is the 'table-layout: fixed;' which I had never come across before. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem via JavaScript. I couldn't find a way to make all the browsers play nice without forcing them.

I basically loop over each image checking what their parent tables size was supposed to be, then divide that by the number of rows to find the image height and by columns for width.